# JNI - Async task crashing

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I'm trying to do the following :

- Run Java app on Android
- Call native C++ code from that Java app
- Create and run a native thread from that natice code
- return immediatly while the thread keeps running
- Call a java method from native code once the thread is finished

Here is my code :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* sleep() */
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_xxx_asynctasktest_MainActivity_runAsyncTask( JNIEnv * env, jobject that, jstring oDummyStr );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


JavaVM *  g_jvm;
jobject   g_obj;
jmethodID g_mid;


void * threadProc( void * pArg )
{
    JNIEnv * env = 0;
    int res = g_jvm->AttachCurrentThread( & env, NULL );

    sleep( 3 );

    jobject oStr = (jobject)pArg;
    env->CallObjectMethod( g_obj, g_mid, oStr );

    env->DeleteGlobalRef( oStr );
    env->DeleteGlobalRef( g_obj );

    g_jvm->DetachCurrentThread();

    return 0;
}


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_xxx_asynctasktest_MainActivity_runAsyncTask( JNIEnv * env, jobject that, jstring oDummyStr )
{
    env->GetJavaVM( & g_jvm );
    g_obj = env->NewGlobalRef( that );
    g_mid = env->GetMethodID( env->GetObjectClass( that ), "onTaskFinished", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;" );

    if( g_mid == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "No such method" );
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_t thread = 0;
        pthread_create( & thread, NULL, threadProc, (void *)env->NewGlobalRef( oDummyStr ) );
    }

    return env->NewStringUTF( "lolol" );
}
```

My problem is that when i call `env->CallObjectMethod( g_obj, g_mid, oStr );`  eclipse tries to open Handler.class in the class file editor and says not found and the thread doesn't call the Java method.

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

EDIT : Forgot to mention that my Java callback creates a dialog as follows :

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );                      
    dlgAlert.setMessage( msgBoxText );
    dlgAlert.setTitle( "" );              
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton( "OK", null );
    dlgAlert.setCancelable( true );
    dlgAlert.create().show();
```

And i'm having a runtime exception somewhere in "Handler" at line 121, source file not available.

EDIT : I'm actually reaching the Java callback, but it crashes when i start creating my dialog.

Comment: You really should include your stack trace in your post.  However, it sounds like your problem is quite simple - you cannot touch the UI from anything but the main thread.  The easiest solution is probably to call a java method which wraps your UI operations in runOnUiThread().  Of course you also have to have all the jni stuff right, and have your native thread registered with the VM - but it sounds like maybe you already worked those parts out.

Comment: Instead to create a method to wrap `runOnUiThread`, you could use handle and broadcast to access the UI element.